# C++ std::map - insert and get iterator - PHP like variable access

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constants

i'm writing a class `CScope` holding variables (string -> value associations). I would like to create a method that would allow me to access `CValue` objects by reference but that would behave in two different ways depending on the fact that we access it for reading or writing.

Here is what i have so far :

```
class CScope
{
    PROTECTED map<string, CValue> _mVars;

    PUBLIC inline const CValue & access( const string & __rsName ) const
    {
        map<string, CValue>::const_iterator oItr = this->_mVars.find( __rsName );

        if( oItr != this->_mVars.end() )
        {
            return oItr->second;
        }
        else
        {
            throw; // TODO Error.
        }
    }

    PUBLIC inline CValue & access( const string & __rsName )
    {
        map<string, CValue>::iterator oItr = this->_mVars.find( __rsName );

        if( oItr != this->_mVars.end() )
        {
            return oItr->second;
        }
        else
        {
            return this->_mVars.insert_at(
        }
    }
};
```

If we access in read-only (const) and if the variable doesn't exist, an error has to be raised. However if we access in write mode (not const), i want the variable to be created if it doesn't exist. Like in PHP :

```
$undeclaredVar = 10; // OK, no need to declared it. = accesses in write mode.
$undeclaredVar = $otherUndeclaredVar + 10; // Error, + accesses in read mode.
```

In the case where i access in write mode, I would like to avoid being forced to first insert the value and then find it, because it would cause 2 hash calculations and i want something optimized.

Isn't there a method in std::map that allows me to insert a value and get the iterator to the newly inserted element without having to compute the hashing (and any other expensive work) twice ? Insert seems to do that but it doesn't seem to have the overload i need, i.e `iterator insert( const key &, const value & )`

Thank you :)

EDIT :

I found a way :

```
return this->_mVars[ __rsName ]; // Operator[] creates if not found.
```

Comment: Accessing an element via the [] operator in std::map creates a default constructed entry for said object if it doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I just realized that. :)

Comment: You shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `__rsName`.